# .Net CSOM and X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a SharePoint 2010 production site which is configured for claims authentication. But when we access the site with .net client object model code we are getting 403 forbidden error.

But if we use "X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f" in request header (which uses windows authentication) , .net CSOM can access the site.

Can we say that the SharePoint site is not properly configured for claims authentication, and this is why the production  site is not accessible with .net  csom except we provide "X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED","f" ?